# Store Widgets in Dictionary

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to store my various checkboxes in a dictionary so that I can later call upon them. Since I would like to perform actions based on the number of widgets with `len(self.il['Line2'])` I need some way of storing them all in an array. Storing each of widgets in a unique entry like:

```
for i in range(7): #INPUT LINE 2
        self.il['Line2',i] = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.il2info[i],self)
print(self.il['Line2',i])

--------output----------
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QCheckBox object at 0x0000021A4398EE58>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QCheckBox object at 0x0000021A4398EF78>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QCheckBox object at 0x0000021A439690D8>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QCheckBox object at 0x0000021A43969168>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QCheckBox object at 0x0000021A439691F8>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QCheckBox object at 0x0000021A43969288>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QCheckBox object at 0x0000021A43969318>
```

but then my `len(self.il['Line2'])` command does not work.
I have tried something like the following:

```
self.il['Line2'[i]] = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.il2info[i],self)
```

but get an error of:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I have also tried to do:

```
self.il['Line2':[i]] = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.il2info[i],self)
```

but I am met with the following error of:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Is there some syntax error that I am missing? Can widget objects not be stored in dictionaries? Is there a way for me to ID widgets that would allow me to store the ID in dictionary?

**EDIT:** My original problem has been solved as I was incorrectly defining the keys/values of my dictionary. Using a temp dictionary to collect all widgets into an array and then equating them to my master dictionary with a key of 'Line2' fixed the issue.

Comment: You're storing a slice object, not whatever your desired key is. Can you update your example?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. I would like the "object" to be stored as a value for my 'Line2' key. I do not want the object to be sliced.

Comment: @JN3 see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an element as follows:

```
d[val1, val2] = some_value
```

is similar to:

```
d[(val1, val2)] = some_value
```

That is, the key is a tuple, so you must pass the tuple as a key so that it returns the value.

```
new_value = d[(val1, val2)]
```

In your case:

```
 self.il['Line2', i]  = some_value
 new_value = self.il['Line2', i]
```

When you indicate for example:

```
self.il['Line2'[2]]
```

It is equivalent to:

```
self.il['n']
```

Or worse if you pass an index higher than the number of letters.

```
self.il['Line2'[6]]
```

**Note**: What you put a tuple as a key does not generate an array, if you want to get the structure of an array you must create a dictionary with dictionaries.

```
tmp_dict = {}
for i in range(7):
    tmp_dict[i] = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.il2info[i],self)
self.il['Line2'] = tmp_dict
```

Then when you want to access you use:

```
#read
new_value = self.il['Line2'][i] 
#write
self.il['Line2'][i]  = some_value
```

Example:

```
for i in range(len(self.il['Line2'])):
    new_value = self.il['Line2'][i] 
    self.il['Line2'][i]  = some_value
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, what I have been doing is creating a bunch of unique keys, and not one key 'Line2' with multiple values. A key that has an array of values would require dictionary within dictionary?

Comment: @JN3 I have added an example of how to do it

Comment: Can I determine the number of values in self.il['Line2'] by using the len() command?

Comment: Yes, `len()` is for  iterables, and the dictionary of those that belong to the list.